# Shake effect jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I have a very simple piece of code taken directly from:
http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/

I want to change it so the distance is 60 instead of the default 20.

This does not work:

```
$( "#toggle" ).effect( {distance:60} );
```

What is the correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the type of effect along with `effect` function. Something like this:

```
$( "#toggle" ).effect('shake', {distance:60} );
```

Check the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cL79S/) - [cL79S](http://jsfiddle.net/cL79S/).

Comment: Thanks!  Just curious, where did you find this info? Or something similar?

Comment: I guess what was missing for me was the {} and knowing that you need that.